# how to fill a matrix with values extracted from another matrix in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

i want to fill a matrix in opencv with values of an other matrix already filled,

this is the first matrix :

```
Mat vv = Mat::zeros(800,600, CV_8UC3); //CV_8UC3 is for 3-channel value

for(int jz = 0; jz < 800; jz++)
{ 
  for (int jy = 0; jy < 600; jy++)
  {
    vv.at<cv::Vec3d>(jz,jy,1) = maxy + jy *stepy;
    vv.at<cv::Vec3d>(jz,jy,2) = maxz + (801 - jz) *stepz;

  }

}
```

i want to fill the matrix w with the elements of `vv` as follow :

```
for j1 = 1:800
       for j2 = 1:600
            w = [-k; vv(j1,j2,1);vv(j1,j2,2)];
            w = w / norm(w);
```

thank you for responding

Comment: Give it a shot and let us know if their is an error and what is k?

Comment: i don't know how to, for k is just a simple parameter

Comment: ner, you did it already. Now you just implement your design and then show what you did with errors (which might not happen)